# Reference for spin structure

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, spin-geometry

I am looking for some elementary books (may be introduction) about $\operatorname{Spin}$ structures in general, and $\operatorname{Spin}$ structure on Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: Here is a short paper of lecture notes. The first couple of pages introduce $Spin$ and $Spin^c$ structures on 4-manifolds. http://php.indiana.edu/~pkirk/papers/SW%20seminar%20notes.pdf

Comment: You might find these notes helpful: http://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/Spin/SpinNotes.pdf

Comment: Milnor has a classic paper in l'enseignement mathematique on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

*Spin Geometry* by Lawson and Michelson is highly regarded. It seems to cover a lot of very important material.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively there is also *Dirac Operators in Riemannian Geometry* by Thomas Friedrich.